# How to track in which direction user is looking in unity oculus VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am new to unity and testing VR development with Oculus quest 2 using XR Plugin management. I want to make a simple program where if user looks at left or right side I want to console it. It would be great if anyone can guide me or refer me to some good tutorial or docs.

Comment: Somebody must be really hating. I asked a question. Got the answer and after a few days someone closed the question

Comment: This question got three votes for "needs author edit" and it **is** opinion based. What I think is a good tutorial could be completely different from what you think is good. That is what your own research should do for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab a reference to the camera, it will be always oriented the way the user is looking, convert it to Euler, and its Y will tell you the angle on the vertical axis. More important issue is - you need to establish what do you mean by left and right - in a way the user is always looking forward, left and right are relative against something. It would probably be best to have a reference transform on the scene that establishes a 'forward' direction, you could then 'flatten' both forward vectors (zero out y component of the transform.forward), and use Vector3.SignedAngle(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, Vector3.up); to get a value in degrees, you can use directly - negative angle whill be left while positive will be right (possibly the other way around, depending on parameter order).